# Control output of c++ program using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have an executable called print-word-length.cc that takes prints the length of words using from a *.txt file.

So in my makefile, `./print-word-length </dir/dictionary.txt` prints out words in the dictionary.

How would I go about just printing the first 10 lengths of words in dictionary.txt?

I've tried `head -n 10 ./print-word-length </dir/dictionary.txt`, but it prints gibberish.

Comment: fixed some typos in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a makefile question, it's a shell scripting question.  You solve the problem by writing a shell command at your shell prompt, then you just put that same solution into your makefile.

The `head` utility prints the first lines it reads from standard input or from a file.  It doesn't *run* a command that you give it as an argument.

It's printing the first 10 lines of the contents of your program file, which is binary "gibberish" as you say.

This is what pipes are for:

```
./print-word-length.cc </dir/dictionary.txt | head -n10
```

This says: start `print-word-length.cc` and set it up so whatever it prints to its output is sent to the `head` command as its input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `./print-words.cc </dir/dictionary.txt | head -n 10`? This will print the first ten lines of the output.